# ngRepeat $scope messing with nested ngClick

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

So i have four progress bars that on click open and close via the close button in the top right....problem is the ngrepeat is messing with something....i've tried adding $parent to the child ngClick but it doesnt work. I've looked at all the other stack examples of this and just can't seem to figure out how to apply it to this specific situation

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JorZoE

```
<div class="progress-bar repeat-animation" ng-click="showClose = false" ng-class="!showClose ? 'grow' : ''" progress-morph style="width: {{item.percent}}%" ng-repeat="item in list">
    <div class="close" ng-hide="showClose" ng-click="onClickClose($event)" ><img src="close42.svg" alt=""></div>
</div>
```

Comment: the bars expand and contract correctly here... BUT they all do when you click on any of them, were you intended to expand/contract only the clicked one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assumed that you wanted to open/close the bars individually.

If that's the case, your code wasn't working because you were binding all the progress bars state to the same `$scope` variable.

Having that in mind, I tweaked your code a little bit to make it work, and also used a more readable logic (imho).

Please take a look and let me know:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WbZygb?editors=101

Comment: that's perfect....i was playing around with adding the item but i was having a hard time visualizing an ngRepeat "item" in my controller....thanks so much im going to go study this for a while